# Calculating a Break Even point using Marginal Cost

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Calculus: I am asked to determine the break even point given the following units.

Fixed Cost: \$$3000$,

Marginal Cost: \$$1$,

Selling Price: \$$3$

I know how determine break even from the standard formula but I have never had to calculate it using marginal cost. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If the fixed cost is \$$3000$ and the marginal cost is \$$1$ then the formula for the total cost in dollars of $x$ items is

$$T=3000+1\cdot x$$

Can you finish from there?